Menu Bugs, freezing bugs in 24.04
This is going to be short.
Anytime I reboot my Ubuntu, for some reason it always start from the menu screen, and also I always get 2 docker menus after using Ubuntu for a while.
Can this be fixed?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
